# How can I call one Angular function from another within the same service?

Tags: angularjs

I have defined the following service using AngularJS:

```
myApp.factory('utilitiesService',
    function ($filter) {
      return {
        myFuncA: function (inArg) {
          return "XXXX";
        },

        myFuncB: function (inObj) {
          inObj.c = "CCCC";
          inObj.d = "dddd";
          inObj.newFunc = function() {
            return utilitiesService.myFuncA(
              this.c,
              this.d
            );
          };
          return inObj;
        }
      };
    }
);
```

From outside of this service, I can call `myFuncA()` by injecting `utilitiesService` and then simply doing `utilitiesService.myFuncA("blah blah blah");`

However calling `myFuncB()` the same way fails because it says it doesn't know about `utilitiesService`. So how can I access `myFuncA()` from within `myFuncB()`'s `inObj.newFunc()`?

Note that I cannot reference `utilitiesService` as `this` in the definition of `newFunc()` because in that context, `this` is `inObj`.

Comment: have you tried `this.myFunA`?

Comment: I made major edits to the question that will change your answer significantly. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way to do this:

```
myApp.factory('utilitiesService',
    function ($filter) {
      service = {};

      service.myFuncA = function (inArg) {
        return ("XXXX" + inArg);
      };
      service.myFuncB = function (inObj) {
        inObj.c = "CCCC";
        inObj.d = "dddd";
        inObj.newFunc = function() {
          return service.myFuncA(
            this.c,
            this.d
          );
        };
        return inObj;
      };

      return service;
    }
 );
```

Comment: I made major edits to the question that will change your answer significantly. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Just so you know you have inArg mixed with inObj in your `service.myFuncB` :)

Answer (score 4):

Update:

```js
myApp.factory('utilitiesService',
  function($filter) {
    return {
      myFuncA: function(inArg) {
        return "XXXX";
      },

      myFuncB: function(inObj) {
        var that = this;
        inObj.c = "CCCC";
        inObj.d = "dddd";
        inObj.newFunc = function() {
          return that.myFuncA(
            this.c,
            this.d
          );
        };
        return inObj;
      }
    };
  }
);
```

```js
myApp.factory('utilitiesService',
  function($filter) {

    function myFuncA(inArg) {
      return "XXXX";
    };

    function myFuncB(inObj) {
      inObj.c = "CCCC";
      inObj.d = "dddd";
      inObj.newFunc = function() {
        return myFuncA(
          this.c,
          this.d
        );
      };
      return inObj;
    }

    return {
      myFuncA: myFuncA,
      myFuncB: myFuncB
    }
  });
```

---

You can do:

```js
myApp.factory('utilitiesService',
  function($filter) {
    return {
      myFuncA: function(inArg) {
        return ("XXXX" + inArg);
      },

      myFuncB: function(inArg) {
        return ("YYYY" + this.myFuncA(inArg));
      }
    };
  }
);
```

or if these function doesn't depend on the context:

```
myApp.factory('utilitiesService',
  function($filter) {

    function myFuncA(inArg) {
      return ("XXXX" + inArg);
    }

    function myFuncB(inArg) {
      return ("YYYY" + myFuncA(inArg));
    }

    return {
      myFuncA: myFuncA,
      myFuncB: myFuncB
    };
});
```

Comment: I made major edits to the question that will change your answer significantly. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @Brian's answer above did. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
myApp.factory('utilitiesService',
  function () {
    return {
      myFuncA: myFuncA,
      myFuncB: myFuncB
    };

    function myFuncA(inArg) {
      return "XXXX";
    }

    function myFuncB(inObj) {
      inObj.c = "CCCC";
      inObj.d = "dddd";
      inObj.newFuncVal = function () {
        return myFuncA(this.c, this.d);
      };

      return inObj;
    }
  }
);
```